# How to make the link bold when mouse over d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am creating a weighted tree chart similar like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd).
I want to have an effect that when a mouse hovers over a circle, the link of this circle become thicker or bold. And when the mouse out, the link back to original setting.Is this possible? Can anyone give me some clues? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do hover effect in your css on the SVG element

`circle:hover {
    stroke-width: 4px;
}`

You would need to figure out best way to target the element to meet your specific needs.

Comment: Example with inline style element: `d3.select("#theSvgParentElement").append("style").text("circle:hover { stroke-width: 3px; }");`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the placement of links and nodes in the DOM won't work with any CSS selectors (because the links and nodes are not siblings or parent/child), you'll have to do this with d3 and unique element ids, for example:

```
d3.selectAll('g.node').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "node"+i});
d3.selectAll('path.link').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "link"+i});

d3.selectAll('g.node').each(function(d, i) {
   d3.select('#node'+i).on("mouseover", function() { 
       d3.select('#link'+(i-1)).attr('style', 'stroke-width: 4px');
   }).on("mouseout", function() {
       d3.select('#link'+(i-1)).attr('style', 'stroke-width: 2px');
   });
});
```

This sets a unique id on each node and link, and then sets `onmouseover` for each node to call a function to update the corresponding link's style (and `onmouseout` to undo the style change as well).

This does rely on the assumption that the nodes and links are constructed in the same order, and that there is one root node with no corresponding link. Ideally, you should set the ids on the node and link elements during the construction so you can ensure that the node/link pairs are in the right order for this to work.

Comment: Also, since your example shows nodes and links being constructed dynamically based on user clicks, you'll definitely want to call the mouseover/mouseout code during the construction, so that the new dynamically created elements will have the same hover behavior.